# What does it means if TNS_Names Directory is Empty?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

What does it means if the TNS_Names directory is empty in Preferences GUI of SQL Developer?

[image: Screenshot of Preferences GUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that there is no `tnsnames.ora` file for SQL Developer to use, so you can't use TNS entries when defining connections.

It won't stop you defining other connection types - 'Basic', 'Custom JDBC' etc. - you just won't be able to use 'TNS' as there won't be any options to pick from in the 'Network alias' drop-down; and if you're previously picked one and then removed the `tnsnames.ora` then it won't be recognised any more.